# Search database table using rawQuery

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I' am using [MySQLI Wrapper](https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class) as stated in the [docs](https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class#running-raw-sql-queries) about running rawQuery. Since it doesn't have any function to search database I had write my own. Below is the code that am using.

```
$songs = $db->ObjectBuilder()->rawQuery('SELECT * FROM songs WHERE song_name LIKE ?', array('%test%'));
```

The query returns empty results, yes there are data in the database which should match the search keyword. Any idea what am I doing wrong in the Query?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the structure and content of `songs` but your code seems to be correct. You can try if problem persists when `array('%test%')` is inserted into query by inserting this manually. Try to execute this:

```
$db->ObjectBuilder()->rawQuery("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE song_name LIKE '%test%'");
```

If this query returns empty results then I would suspect that something wrong is either in your query or in the database. Otherwise, there is something wrong with rewriting parameters by `rawQuery` function.